# Printing largest number from a given input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a code to print the largest number from a given input(string) but it is only valid for inputs containing distinct digits and gives an error 'string index out of range' when the input consists of repetitive digits. Why so?
Note: "The concept of list cannot be used"
My  code is as follows:

```
def largest_num(num): 
    nums = ""
    length = len(num)
    while length:
        max_num = num[0]
        for i in num:
            if i > max_num:
                max_num = i
        num = num.replace(max_num,"")
        nums = nums + max_num
        length-=1
    return nums
    
    x = input("Entered number: ")
    a = largest_num(x)
    print(a)
```

Output:

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvhjD.png)

Comment: You mean "largest **digit**" of the number. Try to run your code by hand with paper and pencil and see what happens if a digit appears more than once.

Comment: Is there an indentation problem as well? Is it just a typo or do you have the code like this?

Comment: Please give an example of an input that causes your code to fail. Also, please include the entire error that you recieve (stack trace). It will contain valuable information about what specifically went wrong.

Comment: "from a given input " - are they entering it in the form of a list?  a string of integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Husnian Mehdi - the original code has error in the line - "num.replace(max_num, ""). You could put print statement after that to see what's happening when you input a number with duplicated digits: such as '454'. I also change some variable names to make it more descriptive.  [Hint: that num.replace() statement has removed both duplicated digits....!]

```py
def largest_num(num): 
    ans = ""
    size = len(num)
    
    while size:
        max_digit = num[0]
        
        for n in num[1:]:
            if n > max_digit:
                max_digit = n
        
        ans = ans + max_digit     
        num = num.replace(max_digit, "")
        print(f' num is: {num} now ...')
        
        size -=1  
        print(f' len: {size}')
        
    return ans

x = input("Entered number: ")
```

Comment: Many thanks to you I understood the error in my code. But can you also guide me to rectify the error as I am a beginner in python and was not able to correct my code after reflecting upon it.

Comment: If the post can help you, please accept it and upvote it?  I'll look into and get back to you later (busy now). But the best way to learn Python, it's to learn how to code it in Pythonic way - like my earlier posts suggest.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you. Sure you can take your time, no hurries at my end. But the above code gives the same error 'string index out of range'. You can answer me whenever you are free.Regards

Comment: Why don't try my last night post - largestNum(num) function and try to run it and understand it along with your "expected inputs" in http://www.pythontutor.com/

Comment: Ok. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's more straightforward to take the advantage of the fact that the input is a string, and string can be sorted easily.  Please try the code next:

```py
    from functools import cmp_to_key
    
    def largestNum(num):
        num = [str(n) for n in num]
        num.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda b, a: ((a+b)>(b+a))-((a+b)<(b+a)) ))
        return ''.join(num).lstrip('0') or '0'

    x = input("Entered number: ")
    #a = largest_num(x)
    print(largestNum(x))

    Demo: 
    >>>Entered number: 321895
    985321
    
    >>>Entered number: 10957
    97510
  

    >>>Entered number: 4576889
    
    9887654
    >>> 

 Or simply do the sorting directly (you can convert this to function):
    1. num = list(num).  # num is string input of number
    2. num = num.sort(reverse=True)
    3. largest = int(‘’.join(num))  # answer
```